# How can I set index for json column in mysql 8 with laravel migration

Tags: laravel, indexing, migration

I'm creating a project with laravel 6. One of my table column type is json.
The data format in the table  column is like this:`{age:30, gender:male, nation:china,...}`. I am wondering if there is a way for me to set index for this column with laravel migration. my database version is mysql 8.0.21.
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/massive-performance-gains-on-json-column-queries-using-mysql-virtual-columns-and-indexes-in-laravel-dc7d289a41b3) very helpful for figuring this out. So for your example structure above, you might have a migration that looks like the following:

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('my_table', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->json('my_json_col')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        // add stored columns with an index 
        // index in this is optional, but recommended if you will be filtering/sorting on these columns
        $table->unsignedInteger('age')->storedAs('JSON_UNQUOTE(my_json_col->>"$.age")')->index();
        $table->string('gender')->storedAs('JSON_UNQUOTE(my_json_col->>"$.gender")')->index();
        $table->string('nation')->storedAs('JSON_UNQUOTE(my_json_col->>"$.nation")')->index();
    });
}
```

And this is equivalent to the following mysql statement:

```
create table my_table
(
    id          bigint unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    my_json_col json      null,
    created_at  timestamp null,
    updated_at  timestamp null,
    age         int unsigned as (json_unquote(json_unquote(json_extract(`my_json_col`, _utf8mb4'$.age')))) stored,
    gender      varchar(255) as (json_unquote(json_unquote(json_extract(`my_json_col`, _utf8mb4'$.gender')))) stored,
    nation      varchar(255) as (json_unquote(json_unquote(json_extract(`my_json_col`, _utf8mb4'$.nation')))) stored
)
    collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

create index my_table_age_index
    on my_table (age);

create index my_table_gender_index
    on my_table (gender);

create index my_table_nation_index
    on my_table (nation);
```

And a simple view of the table after creation:

[image]

This example created actual stored columns, which for this scenario i think is what you would want. But you can also make virtual columns, which are created at query time instead of persistent columns, and you would just use the `virtualAs` function instead of the `storedAs` function in the migration.

These functions are documented in the [Column Modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-modifiers) section of the Laravel migration docs, but it doesn't go into detail on JSON columns, this requires a bit more mysql knowledge.
I also found [this article](https://medium.com/@deltazero/mysql-as-smart-json-storage-200e6758f37e) helpful for the mysql side of things for the JSON columns (SemiSQL).